# Matlab graph only plotting one value from For Loop?

Tags: matlab, matrix, graph, matrix-multiplication

I am currently designing a programme which will output a graph for a range of values from 4 to 10 on the x-axis. However when I plot the graph it only plots on point instead of the required 6 points from the For loop. Can anybody please help with this problem?

I have attached my code and my graph:

```
    ![% Inputs
R=0.4;                                          % Radius of Rotor
B=3;                                            % Number of blades
V=2;                                            % Fluid velocity
Rho=998;                                        % Fluid Density
N=9;                                            % Number of Blade Elements
Cp_estimate=0.5;                                % Estimate power coefficient
Alpha_design=4;                                 % Design alpha
Cl_design=1.04;                                 % Design lift coefficient



% Variables
TSR=4;                                          % Initial tip speed ratio
Cp=0;                                           % Initial power coefficient
i=1;                                            % Counter
alpha_new=0;                                    % Initial value for alpha new
axial_induction=0;                              % Initial axial induction factor
tolerance=0.01;                                 % Tolerance Value
Check=1;                                        % Initial check value
axial_induction_old=0;                          % Initial value for old axial induction factor




for TSR=4:10,disp(TSR),                                                                     % TSR from 4 to 10

   while abs(Check)>=tolerance

r_local=\[(R./N)*1; (R./N)*2; (R./N)*3; (R./N)*4; (R./N)*5; (R./N)*6; (R./N)*7; (R./N)*8; (R./N)*9\];
r_over_R=r_local / R;
TSR_local=r_over_R .* TSR;

Phi=(2/3)*atan(1./TSR_local);
C=((8.*pi.*r_local) ./ (B.*Cl_design)).*(1-cos(Phi));
sigma=(B*C) ./ (pi.*r_local.*2);


Cl=\[1.3; 1.1; 1; 0.9; 0.86; 0.83; 0.8; 0.75; 0.5\];                                          % Lift Coefficients
Cd=\[0.027; 0.024; 0.02; 0.019; 0.018; 0.016; 0.013; 0.012; 0.01\];                           % Drag Coefficients




axial_induction= 1 ./ (((4.*(sin(Phi).^2)) ./ (sigma.*Cl_design.*cos(Phi)))+1);
angular_induction= (1-(3*axial_induction)) ./ ((4.*axial_induction)-1);




axial_induction_old = axial_induction;        
TSR_local = TSR*(r_local./R);                                                                 % Local Tip Speed Ratio
Phi = (2/3)*atan(1./TSR_local);                                                               % Angle of Relative Fluid




relative_wind= atan((1-axial_induction) ./ ((1+axial_induction).*TSR));

F=(2/pi).*acos(exp(-(((B/2).*(1-(r_over_R))) ./ ((r_over_R).*sin(relative_wind)))));          % Tip Loss Factor

C_T=(sigma.*((1-axial_induction).^2) .* ((Cl.*cos(relative_wind))+(Cd.*sin(relative_wind)))) ./ ((sin(relative_wind)).^2);


if C_T(:,i)<0.96
    axial_induction=1 ./ (1+(4.*F.*(sin(relative_wind).^2)) ./ (sigma.*Cl.*cos(relative_wind)));  
elseif C_T(:,i)>0.96
    axial_induction=1 ./ (((4.*F.*cos(relative_wind)) ./ (sigma.*Cl))-1); 
end

D=(8./(TSR.*N)).*(F.*(sin(Phi).^2).*(cos(Phi)-((TSR_local).*(sin(Phi)))).*(sin(Phi)+((TSR_local).*(cos(Phi)))).*(1-(Cd./Cl).*atan(Phi)).*(TSR_local.^2));
Cp=sum(D);


Diff=axial_induction-axial_induction_old;
Check=max(Diff(:));



   end

store_Phi(:,TSR)=Phi;
store_TSR_local(:,TSR)=TSR_local;
store_axial_induction(:,TSR)=axial_induction;
store_angular_induction(:,TSR)=angular_induction;
store_relative_wind(:,TSR)=relative_wind;
store_Check(:,TSR)=Check;
store_Diff(:,TSR)=Diff;
store_Cp(:,TSR)=Cp;
store_TSR(:,TSR)=TSR;

end




figure(1)
plot(store_TSR,store_Cp)
hold all
title('Cp vs Tip Speed Ratio')
xlabel('TSR')
ylabel('Cp')][1]
```

Comment: What does store_Cp look like at the end of the loop?  It should be a length-10 vector, but plot will ignore any values that are NaN.  However, initializing it with the 4th value should set values 1-3 to zero, so it must have some non-NaNs.  But then store_TSR(1,[1:3]) will also be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried running your code in Octave, and after correcting a few typos in the code, this is what I get:

[image]

Is this not what you expect?

FYI, the typos I found were as follows:

- Replace `![% Inputs` with `% Inputs`
- Replace `r_local=\[(R./N)*1; (R./N)*2; (R./N)*3; (R./N)*4; (R./N)*5; (R./N)*6; (R./N)*7; (R./N)*8; (R./N)*9\];` with `r_local=[(R./N)*1; (R./N)*2; (R./N)*3; (R./N)*4; (R./N)*5; (R./N)*6; (R./N)*7; (R./N)*8; (R./N)*9];`
- Replace `Cl=\[1.3; 1.1; 1; 0.9; 0.86; 0.83; 0.8; 0.75; 0.5\];` with `Cl=[1.3; 1.1; 1; 0.9; 0.86; 0.83; 0.8; 0.75; 0.5];`
- Replace `Cd=\[0.027; 0.024; 0.02; 0.019; 0.018; 0.016; 0.013; 0.012; 0.01\];`  with `Cd=[0.027; 0.024; 0.02; 0.019; 0.018; 0.016; 0.013; 0.012; 0.01];`

Answer (score 0):

The variable `Check` from `TSR=4` is retained after the first iteration is finished (`Check=0`), so it's used for `TSR=5`, thus the while statement is satisfied. An easy (although not elegant) solution is to defined `Check` immediately after the for statement:

```
for TSR=4:10,disp(TSR),                      
    Check=1;
    while abs(Check)>=tolerance
        r_local=R/N*(1:9)'; % does the same as your code
        %rest of code
    end
    %rest of code    
end`
```

In addition to am304's comments:

The use of `./` (element-wise division) is not needed in certain sections of your code.
Both `R` and `N` are scalars, and do not change in the loop, so `r_local` can also be defined outside the for loop (and shortened as in the code above). Try to only use `./` and `.*` when it is actually necessary.